# Why does GCS url signing requires Service Account Token Creator?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

"Service Account Token Creator" is a recommended-to-avoid permission on GCP, because it allows service account impersonation. Why does Cloud Storage url signing requires this permission? Can I use url signing without it? Or, at least, maybe I can add some restrictive conditions on this permission?

My code that generates the signed url:

```js
const file = bucket.file(`path-to-file.csv`)
const [signedUrl] = await file.getSignedUrl({
  virtualHostedStyle: true,
  action: 'read',
  expires: Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 10)
})
```

Comment: How do you use the GCS signing URL? Can you share that piece of code when you generate the signed URL?

Comment: Are you running your code on your computer? On Google Cloud?

Comment: It's in App Engine

Answer (score 1):

When you use signed URL, you have 2 options to sign it (technically, a signature is "I use a private key to generate the signature, I'm the only one that can do that, and the other can use the public key to validate that I'M the real signer (owner of the private key")

- Have a service account key file, in JSON format that contain the private key of your service account. That's not the case on App Engine because you use the Metadata server, and it's a good thing *(a service account key file is never a good solution)*
- You haven't a private key and you have to ask the [Service Account Credential API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob) to sign the Blob (URL) for you. In that case, the API generate internally a token and sign the data (in your case the URL, but you can sign any blob).

You are in the second solution and you ask the API to generate a token and sign the string for you. Therefore, you need to have the permission to create a token.